# Edge coloring on a weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am writing a program that uses edge coloring on a weighted graph to determine how many edges can be tested in parallel, at what speed, and in what order. I am dealing with graphs of various amounts of nodes/edges.

My current approach to this program is to find the nodes with the highest degree, color the edge with the highest weight, and then find a non-neighboring node with which to repeat the process. I have found this solution to return non-optimal answers more than I would like, and after researching edge coloring a bit more I realize that there seems to be a higher learning curve than I expected to the algorithm.

My question is this: Is there a school of thought or algorithm pertaining to edge coloring on weighted graphs that can reliably find the most efficient number of cycles with the lowest maximum weight per cycle? Is there a better way to approach the question that I am attempting to answer?

I cannot seem to find any research into the topic that pertains closely to what I am trying to do, and I appreciate any advice or sources to read.